# Keep getting this message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sql

Whenever I get to the part of saving the table- it asks me for the ID number but then it comes up with the following error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed"

I can't figure out what the problem is.
Should I use the same ResultSet variable name for all functions?

```java
public class Events {

    public static void ambush(int mymovement) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseConstants.Database);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            System.out.println("You have been ambushed" + "\n" +
                    " You have moved 1 mile" + "\n"
                    + "Your health, ammunition and supplies have reduced by 40%.");

            System.out.println("Enter your ID to save your progress: ");
            Scanner id = new Scanner(System.in);
            int myid = id.nextInt();

              ResultSet ambush = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops
                    + " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);

            while (ambush.next()) {
                statement.execute("UPDATE " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops + " SET " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Health + " = " + (ambush.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) - 40) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies + " = " + (ambush.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) - 40) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo + " =  " + (ambush.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo)- 40) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Location + " = " + (ambush.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Location) + mymovement) +
                        " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);


                if (mymovement == 10) {
                    System.out.println("You have moved 10 miles - you have completed the mission");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (ambush.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your health is 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (ambush.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your supplies are 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (ambush.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your ammunition is at 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (mymovement < 10) {
                    System.out.println("Your progress has been saved - You will be re-directed to the main menu");
                    DatabaseConstants.showMenu();
                }

            }
            ambush.close();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }




    public static void fire(int mymovement) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseConstants.Database);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            System.out.println("Your journey has been affected by fire" + "\n" +
                    " You have moved 2 miles" + "\n"
                    + "Your health and supplies have reduced by 30%. Your ammunition has stayed the same");

            System.out.println("Enter your ID to save your progress: ");
            Scanner id = new Scanner(System.in);
            int myid = id.nextInt();

            ResultSet fire = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops
                    + " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);

            while (fire.next()) {
                statement.execute("UPDATE " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops + " SET " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Health + " = " + (fire.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) - 30) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies + " = " + (fire.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) - 30) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo + " =  " + (fire.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo)) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Location + " = " + (fire.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Location) + mymovement) +
                        " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);


                if (mymovement == 10) {
                    System.out.println("You have completed the mission");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (fire.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your health is 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (fire.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your supplies are 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (fire.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your ammunition is at 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (mymovement < 10) {
                    System.out.println("Your progress has been saved - You will be re-directed to the main menu");
                    DatabaseConstants.showMenu();
                }

            }
            fire.close();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public static void badweather(int mymovement) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseConstants.Database);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            System.out.println("You journey has been affected by bad weather" + "\n" +
                    " You have moved 3 mile" + "\n"
                    + "Your health and supplies have reduced by 20%.");

            System.out.println("Enter your ID to save your progress: ");
            Scanner id = new Scanner(System.in);
            int myid = id.nextInt();

            ResultSet badweather = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops
                    + " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);

            while (badweather.next()) {
                statement.execute("UPDATE " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops + " SET " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Health + " = " + (badweather.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) - 20) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies + " = " + (badweather.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) - 20) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo + " =  " + (badweather.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo) - 20) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Location + " = " + (badweather.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Location) + mymovement) +
                        " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);


                if (mymovement == 10) {
                    System.out.println("You have moved 10 miles - you have completed the mission");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (badweather.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your health is 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (badweather.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your supplies are 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (badweather.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your ammunition is at 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (mymovement < 10) {
                    System.out.println("Your progress has been saved - You will be re-directed to the main menu");
                    DatabaseConstants.showMenu();
                }

            }
            badweather.close();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public static void noEvent (int mymovement) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseConstants.Database);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

            System.out.println("Your journey has not been affected by any adverse event" + "\n" +
                    " You have moved 4 mile2" + "\n"
                    + "Your health and supplies have reduced by 10%.");

            System.out.println("Enter your ID to save your progress: ");
            Scanner id = new Scanner(System.in);
            int myid = id.nextInt();

            ResultSet noEvent = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops
                    + " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);

            while (noEvent.next()) {
                statement.execute("UPDATE " + DatabaseConstants.Table_Troops + " SET " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Health + " = " + (noEvent.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) - 10) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies + " = " + (noEvent.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) - 10) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo + " =  " + (noEvent.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo) - 10) + ", " +
                        DatabaseConstants.Column_Location + " = " + (noEvent.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Location) + mymovement) +
                        " WHERE " + DatabaseConstants.Column_ID + " = " + myid);


                if (mymovement == 10) {
                    System.out.println("You have moved 10 miles - you have completed the mission");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);

                } else if (noEvent.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Health) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your health is 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);

                } else if (noEvent.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Supplies) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your supplies are 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);

                } else if (noEvent.getInt(DatabaseConstants.Column_Ammo) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Your ammunition is at 0%");
                    System.out.println("Your session will now be terminated");
                    System.exit(0);

                } else if (mymovement < 10) {
                    System.out.println("Your progress has been saved - You will be re-directed to the main menu");
                    DatabaseConstants.showMenu();

                }
            }
            noEvent.close();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is interleaving the `ResultSet` and `Statement` instances.
Please refer to:
[java.sql.Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) API:

*By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. **All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a current ResultSet object of the statement if an open one exists**.*

Comment: Also, I would use a `PreparedStatement` for your update. You can construct the string for the update with `DatabaseConstants` and *then* use that as the basic for your actual bind variable statement. A happy side effect is that you can log the bulk of the statement so you're sure it's correct

Comment: I read the information in the java.sql.Statement  - I thought [variablename].close() would close ResultSet and then it moves - I have no idea what I need to put in the statement. I am still learning and have not learnt PreparedStatements yet